# Limit available memory on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: memory, ubuntu, ram, ubuntu-12.10

Is there a efficient way to limit the available memory of the Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit operating system?
I have a 8GB ram memory and I want to make only 1GB available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation of kernel boot params](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) the `mem=xxx` kernel boot param does what you're looking for.

Comment: The link 404s and the page is not found.